# Why is my Chart.JS canvas not destroying?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm currently having issues with Chart.JS, in particular with destroying a multiple charts.

**The setup:**

I'm calling to a geographic data service via their API and then displaying the statistics of a clicked polygon on charts below that. I have tried to programmatically assign these charts and the associated data in an array of object, called `chartPropertyArray`. Each array object contains the variable, data, and chart variables (see object structure below).

Things are set up this way so each Chart.JS Canvas object (varChart) and the associated context information (ctx) that is required by Chart.JS (see below).

**The problem:**

Because each chart must be assigned to an unique variable to be destroyed the charts are placed in their corresponding object in the `chartPropertyArray`.

*I am trying to loop through these objects and destroy all charts in the array, but this isn't working. More charts just keep getting added. What am I doing wrong?*

**Structure of chartPropertyArray:**

```
var chartPropertyArray = [
                {"variable": "popnChart", 
                    "data": [],
                    "label": "Total Population",
                    "ctx": "",
                    "varChart": ""
                },
                {"variable": "densityChart", 
                    "data": [59, 24, 2],
                    "label": "Population Density",
                    "ctx": "",
                    "varChart": ""
                }, 
                {"variable": "familiesChart", 
                    "data": [3, 5, 1],
                    "label": "Family Size",
                    "ctx": "",
                    "varChart": ""
                }, 
                {"variable": "incomeChart", 
                    "data": [12, 45, 78],
                    "label": "Average Income",
                    "ctx": "",
                    "varChart": ""
                }
            ]
```

**Required setup for creating a chart with Chart.JS:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx,
   ...
```

**Example of creating a chart using this method:**

```
i = 0
while (i < chartPropertyArray.length) {
  properties = chartPropertyArray[i]
  properties["ctx"] = document.getElementById(properties.variable).getContext('2d');
  properties["varChart"] = new Chart(properties.ctx, {
    ...
  i++
}
```

**Example of destroying a chart using this method:**

```
i = 0
while (i < chartPropertyArray.length) {
  properties = chartPropertyArray[i]
  properties.varChart.destroy()
  i++
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing something like an if statement that says if undefined or null chart then destroy the chart? Let me know if you need an example. But its just a basic if statement or conditional.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It was totally an issue on my end, though your comment is a good idea. I've posted what I was doing wrong below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was totally my fault. There was a function that set test charts as 0 (basically creating blank charts on startup) that was set to a different variable. This meant that there were always two charts (four pairs of charts in total) overlaid over one another, even though I was successfully destroying one chart each time.

Thanks for the quick feedback :)